# php check if mysql select exists or empty

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

i'm trying to make a check to show content or not:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friendID = ?
        AND userID = ?");

$stmt->bind_param('ii', $id, $connectedUserID);
$stmt->execute();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true && $stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    //do something
} else echo 'you are not allowed to be here';
```

I want to check if there's any row with those two ids.

But it's not working, i tried many different ways like using === or !== false.

Any help?

Ty!

Comment: as said, the bind_param method doesn't runs the uery, you have to use the **execute** method to run your builded query

Comment: Thanks, is that the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely login check does not return true, the following should be enough

```
if(isset($id, $connectedUserID)){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT *
            FROM friends
            WHERE friendID = ?
            AND userID = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $id, $connectedUserID);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        //do something
    } else{
        echo 'you are not allowed to be here';
    }
}else{
    //redirect to login
}
```

If the user need to be logged in then this is not the place to check for that, it should be prior to this query.

Comment: Yes, the user needs to be logged in, but if $connectedUserID = $_SESSION['user_id']; is empty he won't be able to pass the if. So is that enough, right?

Comment: yes exactly, this logic has a flaw, because you need to be connected to get the value for this params, so that should be checked before running the query

Comment: ok added a if with login_check function... I don't know if calling too much times this function can broke it or something :P

Comment: You just need to make sure the session are set before the query. let me know if you need more help

Comment: I have it this way, "if login_check == true" and inside "if $stmt->num_rows > 0". The problem is that I don't know if it works because I'm logged in and the script sends me to the else... i think it's because I'm already using login_check by comparing it to false... I mean, i need to use it many time and not always true.

Comment: @ChazyChaz I expanded on my answer

Comment: $_GET['id'] and $_SESSION['user_id'] but it's not working, it sends me to you are not allowed to be here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62228/discussion-between-meda-and-chazy-chaz).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a simple '=' or declare a boolean variable and set it 'true' and then compare

Also read:

- [PHP: Comparison Operators](http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/comparison-operators.php)
- [PHP: Logical Operatos](http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/logical-operators.php)